# In Ruby, how do I break up a string given an array of indexes I want to break the string on?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, substring

I have this expression for getting the indexes of spaces in a given string …

```
a = (0 ... cur_line.length).find_all { |i| cur_line[i,1] == ' ' }
```

What I want to do is take the indexes returned by the above expression and use them to break up other strings on those indexes.  So, for instance, if the above contains

[3, 6, 10]

and I have the string

abcdefghijklmnopqrs

Then I would want to take indexes, use them to break up the above string, and get an array containing

```
[“abc”, “def”, “ghij”, “klmnopqrs”]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: This is a ruby question, not a rails question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the easiest way to achieve your goal:

```
def split_by_indices(indices, string)
    result = []
    indices.unshift(0)
    indices.each_with_index do |val, index|
      result << string[val...(index == indices.length - 1 ? string.length : indices[index+1])]
    end
    result
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ruby's [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`String#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-slice) methods, passing in a hash as the initial value to `reduce` to keep track of both the new array you're creating, and the indice to start slicing from in the string.  Each of the indices would then represent where the slice should end, so in order to get the final string, we'd add `str.length` as the final indice:

```
str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrs'
indices = [3, 6, 10]

result = [*indices, str.length].reduce({ array: [], slice_from: 0 }) do |memo, index|
  memo[:array] << str.slice(memo[:slice_from]...index)
  memo[:slice_from] = index
  memo
end

p result[:array]
# => ["abc", "def", "ghij", "klmnopqrs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [3, 6, 10]
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrs'
[0, *a, s.length].each_cons(2).map{|i,j| s[i...j]}
#=> ["abc", "def", "ghij", "klmnopqrs"]
```

Apparently, since 2.3, Ruby also has [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while), but it's somewhat cumbersome in this case:

```
s.chars.each_with_index.chunk_while{|_,(_,i)| !a.member?(i)}.map{|n| n.map(&:first).join}
#=> ["abc", "def", "ghij", "klmnopqrs"]
```

Comment: TIL [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).  Nice answer; should have known a method that does something like that would exist in Ruby.